# How many inverses has each element of commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook says that in an associative ring with element $1$ each element has no more than one inverse element. What about commutative rings?

I think I can prove the same property using commutativity instead of associativity:
$$ a_1^{-1} = a_1^{-1} \times 1 = a_1^{-1} \times a \times a_2^{-1} = a \times a_1^{-1} \times a_2^{-1} = a_2^{-1}$$

Where $a_1^{-1}$ and $a_2^{-1}$ are both inverses of a.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to be wrong?

Comment: @Qwerty 1) If it would be true, I think my textbook would say so.|
2) I think this would imply that associativity can be substituted by commutativity, and I'm currently try to convince myself that this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaving out parentheses, so you are already using that your ring is associative... If you assume your ring to not be associative, your proof won't work. To see that put parentheses and try to prove your claim without just leaving them or changing their position, you will run into quite some trouble there.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your working; your conclusion is correct. However, a ring *is associative by definition*. That includes commutative rings. There's no need to prove this separately via the abelian property.

Also of note is that a (multiplicative) left-inverse is the same as a right-inverse in any ring:

$$a_{L}^{-1} = a_L^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot a_R^{-1}) = (a_L^{-1} \cdot a) \cdot a_R^{-1} = a_R^{-1}$$

Comment: According to my textbook, rings are not associative by definition. It's arithmetic properties of rings are. But I'm talking about multiplicative ones.

Comment: @PaulVergeev - How old is your textbook? I believe there are conflicting definitions floating around, but associativity is assumed by almost all authors I think.

Comment: It's year 2000 edition. I've googled around and you're right, this is something assumed in other books. I'll beware of such things in the future, thank you!

Comment: @PaulVergeev - I'm glad you found it helpful. Please note that I made a mistake in my answer (now corrected). Commutative rings are not necessarily fields (since they may not have inverses).

Answer (score 0):

Inverses have to be unique for the operation to be well-defined. It can be shown that your a<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> = a<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup>

Comment: So, how can I fix my operation so that $a_1^{-1} = a_2^{-1}$ could only be proven using associative property?

Comment: @PaulVergeev You already can. $a_1^{-1}=a_1^{-1}(aa_2^{-1})=(a_1^{-1}a)a_2^{-1}=a_2^{-1}$